# Find and append nested <ul> to select menu with hyphens

Tags: javascript, html-lists

Trying to create a  navigation from an existing menu, here's the markup:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="?=home">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="?=sub-1">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="?=sub-2">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="?=sub-3">Sub 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="?=sub-4">Sub 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="?=sub-5">Sub 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?=about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?=services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?=portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?=contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the javascript loop I have, which currently finds and appends each top level menu item, but I really am unsure how to target the nested children and append them with a hyphen for nested elements.

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    var list = nav.children.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < list; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = nav.children[i].children[0].innerHTML;
        option.value = nav.children[i].children[0].href;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
```

So it would basically do this:

```
<select>
    <option value="?=home">Home</option>
    <option value="?=sub-1">- Sub 1</option>
    <option value="?=sub-2">- Sub 2</option>
```

Etc. etc...

Any help would be massively appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: jQuery would simplify this a lot. Have you considered using it?

Comment: @ColinPear Yes I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: @harsha An HTML5 element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse your ul recursively.  That will handle multilevel menus as well.  Keep track of the recursion level and the higher level items to concatenate with the dashes.

A description of the approach: http://blog.swapnilsarwe.com/javascript-traversing-html-dom-recursively.html

---

**Edit**: Here's an example.  You'll also need to put an HTML select element with id='select' somewhere:

```
buildSelect(document.getElementById('nav'), '', document.getElementById('select'));

function buildSelect(current, optionSoFar, select) {
    var currentLevelOption = optionSoFar;
    for (var i=0; i<current.children.length; i++) {
        var child = current.children[i];
        if ('A' == child.tagName) {
            var currentLevelLabel = child.innerText;
            var separator = ('' == optionSoFar) ? '' : ' - ';
            currentLevelOption = optionSoFar + separator + currentLevelLabel;
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerText = currentLevelOption;
            option.value = child.href;
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
        else {
            buildSelect(child, currentLevelOption, select);
        }
    }
}
```

​
​
Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GM54F/3/

Comment: Thanks! I'm just not sure what that would look like.

Comment: @Todd: Is it OK to optimize the HTML structure?  Currently,  it's too irregular.  A regular ul would only contain any number, in any order, of 1) li with only one a inside 2) another regular ul.  Easy to traverse and style.

Comment: The HTML structure isn't the final solution, it's merely to represent what I wanted to achieve. It was just easy to code it as a demo to show how it would work :-) thanks!

Comment: @Todd: I was wrong; the HTML is just fine.  See the edited answer.  It's based on your code but tweaked a little.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks :) appreciate your help a lot. Have a great new year.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery. [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UxNeg/) that demonstrates this example based off of your code. This would be so much simpiler than writing your own custom code to traverse the DOM yourself.

```
$("#nav a").each(function(){
 myValue = $(this).attr("href");
 myText = $(this).text();    
 $("#mySelect").append("<option value="+myValue + ">" + myText +"</option>");         
});
```